# Whether two sets are equal when the mapping function is same

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

From [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403122/when-do-two-functions-become-equal)
I understood when we can say that two functions are equal. My doubt is can I interpret the same as follows:
Let $X$ , $Y$ and $Z$ be three sets, Let $f : Z \rightarrow X$ and $g : Z \rightarrow Y$, be two functions, then if f = g, we can conclude that $X=Y$.

Comment: It depends on the details... In the [usual def](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) we have that $f$ is defined for every $z \in Z$ but not necessarily every $x \in X$ is in the image of $f$. If so, we may have that $X \ne Y$.

Answer (score 1):

No. If $f: [0,1]\to [0,1]$ and $g: [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ are defined by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x$ for all $x$ then $f=g$.

PS What is involed here is a matter of conventions. Some authors may not consider my functions as equal.

Comment: Then EVERY function is surjective?

Comment: @azif00 No. For surjectivity you have to take the codomain into consideration.

Comment: What I understood from the explained example is, even though the mapping function is same, the codomain seems to be different. But instead of considering the codomain, if we consider the range, then can we say X=Y.

Comment: If two functions are equal then their ranges are equal.

Comment: Thankyou for the insight, can you please provide any reference for the above statement, so that I can do a detailed reading.