# what makes a function invertible?

Tags: inverse, inverse-function, inverse-problems

From what I understand invertible is if we can equate x = f(x) of some form.. Whereas Inverse is where the function can be reflected across the y=x axis. Are those related in any way?

Is it true that only $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ out of these below functions are invertible? If so, why?

---

$f(x)=x^2, f(x)=|x|,  f(x)=\frac{1}{x}, f(x)=2$

Comment: A solution of $x=f(x)$ is a *fixed-point* of $f$. That has nothing to do with being invertible or not.

Comment: Hello :) "Invertible" means, that for all $y$ in the range of $f$, we can find exactly one $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $y=f(x)$.

Comment: A sufficient (but not necessary condition) that a function is invertible within an interval $[a,b]$ is that it is differentiable everywhere in this interval and either $f'(x)>0$ holds for every $x$ in  the interval or $f'(x)<0$ holds for every $x$ in the interval. Equality is allowed on isolated points.

Comment: For each of those functions, you should state the domain over which you are defining them. And a function is invertible if and only if it is *one-to-one* and *onto*, i.e. the function is a *bijection*. This is not necessarily a *definition* of invertible, but it a useful and quick way of deciding if a function is invertible. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Definitions

Comment: In all but the $f(x)=1/x$ choice, the value of $f(x)$ is defined, and is the same, at $x=1$ as it is at $x=-1.$ So those functions are not invertible.

Comment: It seems that your understanding of invertibility is more "graphical" than by definition. Can you plot these graphs accurately? The criteria you've written for *functional* invertibility is almost correct (the reflection across the line $y=x$ should look like a function i.e. for each $x$ there should be only one $y$ such that $(x,y)$ lies on the graph) and I don't understand the $x=f(x)$ part, it'll need more clarity. Rather than focus on the definitions, you should focus on getting your graph, and the reflection correct. Same for the answers.

Comment: sorry so only 1/x is invertible... correct?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is invertible if and only if it is one-to-one. A one-to-one function is a function where no two inputs produce the same output, i.e. for all $a$ and $b$ in the domain of $f$,
$$
f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b \, ,
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
a\neq b\implies f(a)\neq f(b) \, .
$$

As Martin R mentions in the comments, if $f(x)=x$ for some $x$, then $f$ is said to have a "fixed point" at $x$. This has nothing to do with whether $f$ is invertible.

So for each of your functions, you have to consider whether $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $a=b$. For instance, does $a^2=b^2$ imply that $a=b$?

Comment: Doesn't a function have to also be surjective in order for it to be invertible? You don't mention this, but wikipedia does say this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Definitions

Comment: @AdamRubinson: There's not a straightforward answer to that question. It depends on the definition of "function" (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403122/when-do-two-functions-become-equal_)). The simplest definition (and the one I consider to be the best) is that a function $f$ is a set of ordered pairs such that if $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,c)\in f$, then $b=c$. According to this definition, the functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,\,f(x)=\sin x$ and $g:\Bbb R\to[-1,1] ,\,g(x)=\sin x$ are identical. Therefore, to call $f$ non-surjective and $g$ surjective is non-sensical.

Comment: A function can only be surjective onto a particular set. So $f$ and $g$ are both surjective onto $[-1,1]$, and not surjective onto $\Bbb R$. Note also that when we write $f:A\to B$, the set $B$ is just intended to be *any* superset of the range of $f$, and changing what $B$ is doesn't change the definition of $f$. However, if you define functions in a different way, then the answer is also very different.

Answer (score -1):

$f$ is invertible (or injective) if whenever $f(x)=f(y)$, we have $x=y$. Or equivalently for each $z$ in the range of $f$ there is only one $x$ such that $f(x)=z$. For $1,2$ and $4$ you should try to find $f(x)=f(y)$ where $x\neq y$.

**Hint:**
For $1$ we have $1^2=(-1)^2$.

Comment: The first sentence is not equivalent to the second.  The function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=e^x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @Randall Sorry, of course I meant range.