# If we want $x^n$ to have an inverse for all non-zero integers $n$, what must the domain of $x$ be?

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

**Background**

Let $f(x) = x^n$ with $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $x \in \mathbb R$.

For $f$ to have an inverse, $n$ must be odd.

**Question**

Can we change the domain of $x$ such that $x^n$ has an inverse for all integers $n$ except $0$?

Comment: Of course, and it is commonly done as follows: take $(0,\infty)$ as a (smaller) domain.

Comment: @StinkingBishop - I'm ashamed. Obviously the function would be strictly increasing or decreasing on this domain.

Comment: @Alec Not necessarily. Here is a silly example: define $f(x)=x^n$ on nonnegative algebraic numbers and negative transcendental numbers. Then for even $n$, $f$ is not increasing or decreasing on its whole domain, but it's nevertheless a bijection from its domain to $\Bbb R^+$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every integer $n\neq0$, the function $f_n:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ given by $f_n(x)=x^n$ is monotone, and so it is one-to-one, and so it is invertible.

The proof that each $f_n$ is monotone is simple: if $n>0$, then $a>b>0\implies a^n>b^n$; this can be easily seen from the identity
$$
a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+b^{n-1}) \, .
$$
If $n<0$, then $-n>0$, so $a>b>0\implies a^{-n}>b^{-n}$; rearranging this final inequality gives us the desired result.

Comment: The counter-domain has to be $(0, \infty)$ for this to work (just a small detail, but I guess I’m picky…)

Comment: @Gauss: That's true if you include the codomain as part of the definition of a function. Personally, I prefer to define a function as a set of ordered pairs $f$ such that if $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,c)\in f$, then $b=c$. In this approach, the inverse of $f$ is defined as the set $$f^{-1}=\{(b,a):(a,b)\in f\} \, .$$

Comment: @Gauss: Under this set-theoretic definition of function (which can be found in Michael Spivak's *Calculus*, for instance), the functions $f:\mathbb R_{\ge0}\to\mathbb R,f(x)=x^2$ and $g:\mathbb R_{\ge0}\to\mathbb R,g(x)=x^2$ are identical, and they both have inverses. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403122/when-do-two-functions-become-equal) thread for more details.

Comment: I guess you make a fair point. You can always assume a restriction to the image in order to invert it, anyway. Thank you for the reference, by the way!

Comment: @Gauss: No problem! By the way, my above comment had a typo: I meant to write that the functions $f:\mathbb R_{\ge0}\to\mathbb R,f(x)=x^2$ and $g:\mathbb R_{\ge0}\to\color{\red}{\mathbb R_{\ge0}},g(x)=x^2$ are identical in this definition of function. This means it no longer makes sense to talk about whether a function is "surjective" or not, and so it is understable that in some areas of mathematics the set-theoretic definition of "function" is not preferred.